# i can't map my array stored in local storage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

using useState and useEffect hooks, i stored my array in local storage.

```
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("arrKey")

    const [arr, setArr] = useState(data || [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setArr(JSON.parse(data))
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("arrKey", JSON.stringify(arr))
    },[arr])
```

i also want to display it on my page. everytime a new user input gets pushed to the array, it supposed be added to the displayed list items. now if i display the array as a whole, it works just fine. but when i try to display the elements one by one with the map function, i get this error:

[image]

here is my code:

```
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h2>Enter numbers</h2>
                <input type={"number"} name={"newnum"}/>
            </form>
            <ul>
                {arr.map(num => (
                    <li>{num}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: Probably because the default value of setState is the string value of your local storage. Just set an empty array as default value and it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState(data || [])
```

This will assign the string value of `data` to `arr`.

Since strings don't have the map, you'll get that error.

You could just assign an empty array to the useStat, then your logic inside the useEffect will assign the actual array to the useState, and skip the string variant. So use `useState([])`

---

You could also do the JSON.parse on `data`, then your current useState will work as expected

Comment: i added JSON.parse and it worked. thanks sm.

Answer (score -1):

My assumption is that at some point in the lifecycle, arr is null before it's populated. It should be able to be solved by adding a default or a guard condition in your JSX.

```
{arr && arr.map(num => (
  <li>{num}</li>
))}
```